# Executing stored procedure in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

While calling the stored procedure of mysql using python, I am getting a syntax error.

The code for the stored procedure is as follows,

```
while True:
    try:
      date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
      temp,humidity,light = main.reading()
      args= (192.168.1.145, b8:27:eb:06:e4:4b, Temp_PI, temp)
      cursor.callproc('SPR_IU_Sensor_Data',args)
      conn.commit()
      time.sleep(interval2)
    except:
        MySQLdb.Error, e:
        conn.rollback()
        print "Transaction aborted: %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
```

The error is as follows;

```
  File "procedure.py", line 53
    args= (192.168.1.145, b8:27:eb:06:e4:4b, Temp_PI, temp)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to *quote* the ip addresses, pass them in as *strings*:

```
args = ('192.168.1.145', 'b8:27:eb:06:e4:4b', Temp_PI, temp)
```

Python has no notion of an IP address literal notation.